# About Smoke Grenades and Sugar Rockets

Tags: everyday-chemistry, combustion, fuel

The most common formula for smoke grenades and sugar rocket fuel is $60\%\ \ce{KNO3}$ (potassium nitrate) and $40\%\ \ce{C12H22O11}$ (sugar). This is a 3:2 ratio, but I've also seen 2:1 and 5:3 with similar results.

The formulas I've seen (https://www.scienceforums.net/topic/19364-kno3-and-sugar-smoke-bomb/) are: $\ce{5C12H22O11 + 48KNO3 -> 24K2CO3 + 36CO2 + 55H2O + 24N2}$ and $\ce{C12H22O11 + 24KNO3 -> 24KNO2 + 12CO2 + 11H2O}$.

Based on the first formula, using mole ratios and molar masses, it would be ideal to have $\pu{68.5 g} \;(\pu{0.2 mol})$ of sugar mixed with $\pu{194.1 g} \;(\pu{1.92 mol})$ of oxidizer. This is not even close to the advertised 3:2 ratio, being a 17:6 ratio.

**Question 1: Why do you need substantially less potassium nitrate than as indicated by the chemical equation?**

Now, in terms of the smoke grenade, an alternate formula I've seen used involves potassium chlorate (oxidizer) and lactose (same as sucrose). This, from what I've read, burns at a lower temperature and can produce colored smoke.

**Question 2: Which one produces more smoke than the other (and why)?**

**Question 3: How can I modify the $\ce{KNO3}$ formula to produce more smoke. Which reactant produces the smoke? Fuel (sucrose/lactose) or oxidizer (K-nitrate/K-chlorate)?** From a 60:40 ratio, should I add more sugar to make it like a 40:60 ratio, or more potassium nitrate, therefore 70:30 is better?

Comment: I'm not sure the reaction is correct, I've found another [source](http://people.bu.edu/straub/courses/demomaster/no3periodic.html) with the following reaction: $\ce{2KNO3(s) + CH2O(s) → 2KNO2(s) + CO2(g) + H2O(g)}$, $\ce{CH2O}$ being an empirical formula for glucose, which is actually $\ce{6 x CH2O}$. The ratio would still be off (about 6:1), not sure why. Maybe the recipes simply work with an excess of sugar?

Comment: Well, if there was no air there and you you didn't want any, well, *smoke*, then putting that much oxidiser would be proper.

Comment: @Mithoron Are you saying that more sugar would release more smoke? I kinda figured that because smoke comes from incomplete combustion, by piling on more organic stuff, more smoke would appear.

Comment: Either you want smoke or a complete reaction.